# cropThumbnailImage creates completely transparent gif image

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, imagick

I'm trying to create thumbnail out of gif image. No matter which image I use, Imagick creates completely transparent image. On other formats I don't have this problem. This is my code:

```
// $file = 'somefile.gif'
$inFile = $file;
$outFile = public_path() . "/thumbs/" . $filename;

$image = new Imagick($inFile);

$image->cropThumbnailImage(480, 360);
$image->setImagePage(480, 360, 0, 0);
$image->writeImage($outFile);
```

How can I fix this

Comment: Why are you calling setImagePage? What do you think it does?

Comment: @Danack I found online that it makes better gif images. It basically removes canvas from output image.

Comment: Possible dupe - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950712/crop-bug-in-php-imagick/3988764#3988764 basically if it's an animated gif, you need to call coalesceImages